# How to create this matrix? C

Tags: c, matrix

i want to make matrix :

```
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

but it shown:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The code I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void graphS()
{
    int i,j,k,n,x[10][10];
    printf("S");scanf("%d",&k);
    n=k+1;

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        {
            x[i][j]=0;
            x[i][n-1]=1;
            if(i==j) 
                x[i][j]=0;
            printf("%d\t",x[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    graphS();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do this: (No if else condition)

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        x[i][j]=0;
        x[i][n-1]=1;
        x[n-1][j]=1;//This is the line you need
        if(i==j)
            x[i][j]=0;
        printf("%d\t",x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the following line -

```
for(j=1;j<n;j++){
```

add -

```
if (j==n-1)
x[i][j] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
if (i == n-1) x[i][j] = (j == n-1) ? 0 : 1;
```

So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void graphS(){
        int i,j,k,n,x[10][10];
        printf("S");scanf("%d",&k);
        n=k+1;
        for(i=1;i<n;i++){
            for(j=1;j<n;j++){
                x[i][j]=0;
                x[i][n-1]=1;
                if(i==j) x[i][j]=0;
                if (i == n-1) x[i][j] = (j == n-1) ? 0 : 1; //Added
                printf("%d\t",x[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        graphS();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a bit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void graphS(){
    int i,j,k,n,x[10][10];
    printf("S");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    //n=k+1;
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
        {
            x[i][j]=0;
            x[i][k]=1;
            if(i==k)
            {
                x[i][j]=1;
                x[i][k]=0;
            }
            printf("%d\t",x[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    graphS();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the loops with these one.

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(j=1;j<n;j++){
            if( (i==n-1 && i!=j) || (j==n-1 && i!=j) ) x[i][j] = 1;
            else x[i][j] = 0;
            printf("%d\t",x[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

In your code your assigning 1 to x[i][n-1] only but not to x[j][n-1]

So this cause the output to go wrong. Either you go with my modification or work with your code but add the snippet x[j][n-1] = 1.